# How to change class component to function component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am using Ant design library in reactjs.

How do I change a class component  to function component ?

```
import { Accordion, List } from 'antd-mobile';

class AccordionExmple extends React.Component {
  onChange = (key) => {
    console.log(key);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" className="my-accordion" onChange={this.onChange}>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 1">
            <List className="my-list">
              <List.Item>content 1</List.Item>
              <List.Item>content 2</List.Item>
              <List.Item>content 3</List.Item>
            </List>
          </Accordion.Panel>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 2" className="pad">this is panel content2 or other</Accordion.Panel>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 3" className="pad">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
          </Accordion.Panel>
        </Accordion>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AccordionExmple />, mountNode);
```

This is code example.
I want to use this component as function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const AccordionExmple = () => {
  const onChange = (key) => {
    console.log(key);
  }
 
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" className="my-accordion" onChange={onChange}>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 1">
            <List className="my-list">
              <List.Item>content 1</List.Item>
              <List.Item>content 2</List.Item>
              <List.Item>content 3</List.Item>
            </List>
          </Accordion.Panel>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 2" className="pad">this is panel content2 or other</Accordion.Panel>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 3" className="pad">
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
          </Accordion.Panel>
        </Accordion>
      </div>
    );
}
```